# Differences between columns in MapInfo

Tags: sql, mapinfo

I have two columns in a nodes table, one column has the ground level of the node taken from the model and the other column has the ground level inferred from LiDAR. Is there a query that can be used to select records where one column is greater than the other by a certain value (eg 0.5m).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this via SQL Select:

- Select: *
- From Table(s): NODESTABLE
- Where: GROUNDLEVEL > (LIDARLEVEL + 0.5)

In the example above replace:

- NODESTABLE with the name of your table
- GROUNDLEVEL with the name of the column holding the ground level
- LIDARLEVEL with the name of the column holding the LiDAR level

Also note that the example above will give you the nodes/points where the ground level is larger than the LiDAR level + 0.5 (units).

You can also write the condition like this:

- Where: (GROUNDLEVEL - LIDARLEVEL) > 0.5